# How to prevent Pynput when the application is in background in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pynput

I'm trying to prevent the pynput framework when my GUI is in background. I'm using pynput to make shortcuts for some buttons. I use PyQT5 for GUI.

```py
from pytube import YouTube
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror as hata, showinfo as bilgi, showwarning as uyari, askyesno as soru
from sys import argv, exit as exiting
from threading import Thread as th
from GUI import *
from numpy import arange as range
import sqlite3 as sql
import youtube_dl
import vlc
import time
import os
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from keyboard import is_pressed as pressed, press


def Listener(self):
        def Listener_thread():
            with Listener(on_press=self.onpress) as listener:
                press("X")
                listener.join()
        t1 = th(target=Listener_thread)
        t1.start()


    def onpress(self, key):
        if pressed("ESC"):
            os.system(fr"taskkill /f /im {__file__.split(chr(92))[-1]}")
```

Comment: can you show  your code?

Comment: @codester_09 Sure. I am going to add my codes here right now.

Comment: @codester_09 I just added code. I didn't add all the code due to my code is too long to add here.

Comment: @Deezwend we can't guess your imports, please add them for clarification. for ex. `import threading as th`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch It's `import threading as th` it is `from threading import Thread as th`

Comment: @rv.kvetch Sorry. I forgot to add them. I just added them as well.

Comment: What problem you have??

Comment: @codester_09 Unfortunately it doesn't stop listening to keys when the GUI is in background

Comment: The whole *point* of `pynput` is to deal with mouse/keyboard input in other applications.  Use Qt's own event handling features to deal with input in your own application.

Comment: @jasonharper I did not know it. I need to take a look at how it exactly works.

Comment: @Deezwend keyboard module listens to the keys even if you are not focusing on the window.

Comment: @Deezwend What's your window variable name??

Comment: @codester_09 I didn't understand what you meant. Did you mean the text of the window title?

Comment: @Deezwend Can you show some code where you create the design of the window??

Comment: @Deezwend What is the name of qtcore variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247451/discussion-between-codester-09-and-deezwend).

Comment: if you don't want run functions when PyQt5 is not focus then maybe you should use PyQt5's methods to bind code to keys (instead of Pynput and keyboard) - and they will work only when PyQt5 is focused.

Comment: BTW `Listener` already uses `thread` to run its code and you don't need to use another `thread` to run it. Simply create it in old fashion `listener = Listener()` and run thread as `listener.start()` and don't use `listener.join()`

Comment: @Deezwend For future reference, always take your time to write your questions, don't rush it because you're in a hurry to get an answer (on the contrary, it'll take much more time). Also, always consider to provide a [mre], which should include only the necessary imports to make the code *reproducible*, not *all of them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `pressed` function from the `keyboard` module that listen to keys even if you do not focus the window.

so you have to use the `hasFocus()` or `self.isActiveWindow()` function from the `PYQT5` module

Syntex

```
if pressed("ESC") and self.hasFocus():
            os.system(fr"taskkill /f /im {__file__.split(chr(92))[-1]}")

# or 

if pressed("ESC") and self.isActiveWindow():
            os.system(fr"taskkill /f /im {__file__.split(chr(92))[-1]}")
```